# Drupal Security

Tags: security, drupal-6

Drupal uses every technique to make webisite safe. But what mistakes, while programming will make drupal weak so that I can avoid them while writing custom modules or making .tpl files.

Comment: This really depends on what your module will be for. For example, if it accepts user input, you have to sanitize the input to avoid SQL injection. But there are so many ways to make a website vulnerable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a list of all mistakes, but here's a list of what to do right that includes some mistakes:

- [Secure configuration](http://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration) for Drupal sites
- [Writing secure code](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code) which is also valuable to understand so you can audit the modules you install.
- [Cracking Drupal](http://crackingdrupal.com/) the only book about security in Drupal, which is available in physical or Kindle versions (disclosure: I'm the author ;))

Answer (score 1):

You can make so many mistakes, but one of my favorites is the following:

```
$global user;
if ($user->uid = 1)
{
    //do some magic
}
```

instead of

```
$global user;
if ($user->uid == 1)
{
    //do some magic
}
```

Comment: That's why it is a good technique to write such comparisons the other way around: `if (1 == $user->uid)`. If you forget one equal sign, it doesn't open a hole.